# Erro: python boolean

Tags: python

```
def INSERTION_SORT(A):
    for j in range(len(A)-1):
        key = A[j]
        i = j+1
        print("***********")
        print(j >= 0)
        print(key > A[i])
        print(j >= 0 & key > A[i])

A = [5,2,4,6,1,3]

INSERTION_SORT(A)
```

operation result：

```
***********
True
True
False
***********
True
False
False
***********
True
False
False
***********
True
True
False
***********
True
False
False
[Finished in 52ms]
```

why are all true, the result is false

Comment: That `&` looks suspicious.

Comment: Only for `j >= 0` are "all true", and that's because for `for j in range(len(A)-1)`, all `j >= 0`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator, maybe you meant `and`?

Comment: What is meant by "why are all true, the result is false"? There isn't a result anywhere in this code. It's not clear to me what it's supposed to do, seeing how ``INSERTION_SORT`` doesn't insert anything.

Comment: Did you intend to ``print((j >= 0) & (key > A[i]))``?

Comment: In particular, note that `j >= 0 & key > A[i]` is _not_ `(j >= 0) & (key > A[i])` but `j >= (0 & key) > A[i]`, i.e. `j >= 0 > A[i]`. First comparison is true, second comparison is false for all values, hence the entire chained comparison is false.

Comment: Use the keyword `and`, not `&` because `&` is a bit operator.
In Python `and` and `or` are used for boolean comparisons.

It should be like this

`print(j >= 0 and key > A[i])`

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing answers via edits. The new question state makes the answers fail to even address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `and` keyword instead of `&`

- `and`: this is the logical and
- `&`: this is the bitwise operator

Comment: Note that ``True & True`` is ``True``. The problem isn't that one works "logically" and the other "bitwise".

Comment: The real problem is the different operator precedence. `and` is evaluated after comparisons, whereas `&` is evaluated before.

Comment: So if first condition is false, the other one will not be checked if Im using `&`?

Comment: No, that's lazy evaluation. See my comment on the question. With `&`, there are not "two conditions", but just a single chained comparison.

Comment: Ah ok. Understood thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using the bitwise operator &, in the line `print(j >= 0 & key > A[i])`. Instead you can use `and` logical and operator.
By the way, your code is not yet doing any sorting operation.